# shm_open: Differences between Mac and Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, shared-memory

I have a queue in shared memory. It does work on Linux (kernel 4.3.4), but not on Mac OS X. Are there any differences between how Mac OS X handles shared memory and how linux does, which may explain this?

I get the shared memory via:

```
int sh_fd = shm_open(shmName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 
        S_IROTH | S_IWOTH // others hav read/write permission
        | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR // I have read/write permission
        );

// bring the shared memory to the desired size
ftruncate(sh_fd, getpagesize());
```

The queue is very simple as well. Here is the basic struct:

```
typedef struct {
// this is to check whether the queue is initialized.
// on linux, this will be 0 initially
bool isInitialized;
// mutex to protect concurrent access
pthread_mutex_t access;
// condition for the reader, readers should wait here
pthread_cond_t reader;
// condition for the writer, writers should wait here
pthread_cond_t writer;
// whether the queue can still be used.
bool isOpen;
// maximum capacity of the queue.
int32_t capacity;
// current position of the reader and number of items.
int32_t readPos, items;

// entries in the queue. The array actually is longer, which means it uses the space behind the struct.
entry entries[1];
} shared_queue;
```

Basically everyone who wants access acquires the mutex, readPos indicates where the next value should be read (incrementing readPos afterwards), (readPos+items) % capacity is where new items go. The only somewhat fancy trick is the isInitialized byte. ftruncate fills the shared memory with zeros if it had length 0 before, so I rely on isInitiualized to be zero on a fresh shared memory page and write a 1 there as soon as I initialize the struct.

As I said, it works on Linux, so I don't think it is a simple implementation bug. Is there any subtle difference between shm_open on Mac vs. Linux which I may not be aware of? The bug I see looks like the reader tries to read from an empty queue, so, maybe the pthread mutex/condition does not work on shared memory in a Mac?

Comment: I don't understand which is the connection between `isInitialised` and `ftruncate`. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @terencehill - I'm pretty sure whatever "fancy trick" he's doing with that flag is insufficient (in the general case) for preventing two processes from trying to init the same queue AND guaranteeing that no process ever tries to use an uninitialized queue.  See my edited answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED is not supported on mac.

http://alesteska.blogspot.de/2012/08/pthreadprocessshared-not-supported-on.html

Comment: [OSX man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared.3.html)

Comment: Looks like you're right, which means Alex's solution is just not portable to OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You must set `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` on both the mutex and condition variables.

So for a mutex:

```
pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr;
pthread_mutex_t     the_mutex;

pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutexattr(&the_mutex, &mutex_attr);
```

Basically the same steps for the condition variables, but replace `mutexattr` with `condattr`.

If the the `pthread_*attr_setpshared` functions don't exist or return an error, then it may not be supported on your platform.

To be on the safe side, you might want to set `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` if supported.  This will prevent deadlock over the mutex (though not guarantee queue consistency) if a process exits while holding the lock.

*EDIT*: As an added caution, having a boolean "is initialized" flag is an insufficient plan on its own.  You need more than that to really guarantee only one process can initialize the structure.  At the very least you need to do:

```
// O_EXCL means this fails if not the first one here
fd = shm_open(name, otherFlags | O_CREAT | O_EXCL );  
if( fd != -1 )
{
   // initialize here

   // Notify everybody the mutex has been initialized.
}
else
{
    fd = shm_open(name, otherFlags ); // NO O_CREAT

    // magically somehow wait until queue is initialized.
}
```

Are you sure really need to roll your own queue?  Will POSIX message queues (see `mq_open` man page) do the job?  If not, what about one of many messaging middleware solutions out there?

### **Update 2016-Feb-10: Possible `mkfifo` based solution**

One alternative to implementing your own queue in shared memory is to use an OS provided named FIFO using `mkfifo`.  A key difference between a FIFO and a named pipe is that you are allowed to have multiple simultaneous readers and writers.

A "catch" to this, is that the reader sees end-of-file when the last writer exits, so if you want readers to go indefinitely, you may need to open a dummy write handle.

FIFOs are super easy to use on the command line, like so:

### reader.sh

```
mkfifo my_queue
cat my_queue
```

### write.sh

```
echo "hello world" > my_queue
```

Or slightly more effort in C:

### reader.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  FILE * fifo;
  FILE * wfifo;
  int res;
  char buf[1024];
  char * linePtr;

  /* Try to create the queue.  This may belong on reader or writer side
   * depending on your setup. */
  if( 0 !=  mkfifo("work_queue", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR ) )
  {
    if( errno != EEXIST )
    {
      perror("mkfifo:");
      return -1;
    }
  }

  /* Get a read handle to the queue */
  fifo = fopen("work_queue", "r"); 

  /* Get a write handle to the queue */
  wfifo = fopen("work_queue", "w"); 
  if( !fifo )
  {
    perror("fopen: " );
    return -1;
  }

  while(1)
  {
    /* pull a single message from the queue at a time */
    linePtr = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fifo);
    if( linePtr )
    {
      fprintf(stdout, "new command=%s\n", linePtr);
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

### writer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  FILE * pipe = fopen("work_queue", "w");
  unsigned int job = 0;
  int my_pid = getpid(); 
  while(1)
  {
    /* Write one 'entry' to the queue */
    fprintf(pipe, "job %u from %d\n", ++job, my_pid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, the bool flag is not enough. I usually just waited a few seconds before I started the second process. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For mq_open: If I search for "mac mq_open", this thread is the seventh hit. Are you sure this function exists on Mac OS X (on linux, it might be a good idea).

Comment: [mq_open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mq_open.html) is a POSIX thing, not Linux-specific.  But oddly enough, I guess you are right that OSX does not support it.  OSX *does* support System V message queues (see `msgctl`, `msgsnd`, etc) which is also odd.

Comment: @Alex - You could try [mkfifo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mkfifo.2.html), which gives you a multi-reader, multi-writer safe queue.  The only "trick" to pay attention to is that all readers will see an an `EOF` when the last writer is closed.

Comment: @Alex - see updated answer for a quick example using mkfifo.